# Apache won't release worker threads (mpm-event)

Tags: apache, configuration, ubuntu-18.04, lucee

I've been having issue with the mpm event module in apache. For a client of ours we have an apache/lucee webserver. Apache functions as the pass through in function of a proxy to the lucee webserver.

We seem to have an issue that causes apache to keep the threads locked. I've noticed this because i use the server-status functionality built into apache.

I already tinkered with the conf file for the mpm-event module and it currently sits as follows:

```
StartServers            16
MinSpareThreads         480
MaxSpareThreads         480
ThreadsPerChild         30
MaxRequestsPerChild     1000
MaxClients              480
ThreadLimit             64
ServerLimit             16
```

The server is an ubuntu 18.04, has 4 cores and 16gb of ram, it has apache 2.4.29, lucee 5.3.4.37 and a nodejs v11.2.0 service installed and running through pm2.

I ran some loadtests with jMeter and everything went fine performance wise. It's just apache that doesnt seem to let go of the threads. Most of the time they stay in status "R" Reading Request, "W" Sending Reply or "G" Gracefully finishing. Once the amount of connections are saturated, apache hangs, and I need to restart the apache service.

```
______R______________________________________............G..__RR
R___R____________________________________R______________RRRRRR_R
R___RR________RRRRRW__RR_____________.GGGGGGG....G...G.....G....
.......G.G...G..G.......G....G.........G.G......
```

I've checked apache error logs but couldn't find anything. Same for the lucee error logs and the nodejs error logs.

I've read through a lot of topics regarding this and tried almost every solution I could find. This is going on for some time now so I might not remember everything I already tried.

Any input is appreciated.

edit:
i'm connecting to lucee as follows:

```
        TimeOut 50
        ProxyTimeout 30
        ProxyBadHeader IsError
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/$1$2 connectiontimeout=2 timeout=30 retry=30 ttl=30
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/$1$2 connectiontimeout=2 timeout=30 retry=30 ttl=30
```

EDIT2: I've might have found a solution to the issue, although maybe not the best one. It seems that when you disable the KeepAlive property in apache the connections/threads are released as they should...

Comment: Can you include what connection method you're using between Apache and Lucee?

Comment: I've added the connection method to the original post.

Comment: Those timeouts are inconsistent and really short. I'm guessing you've been testing configs? What happens if you simply use the defaults - ie: remove everything above "ProxyPreserveHost" and remove everything after "$1$2" on those two bottom lines? I'm wondering if the shortness is hurting you...

Comment: I've started with the original config for lucee/apache which indeed doesnt have those timeouts. But the issue was the same unfortunately

Comment: Try adding a timeout to the Tomcat side. That way, if it's Tomcat that is waiting to hear back from something, it can close the connection properly. You can do this by editing the tomcat server.xml file's connector statement. Something like this:

<Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="30000" redirectPort="8443" />

... this will set the timeout to 30 seconds.